# Monotouch: Deserialize JSON from MVC to Montouch

Tags: json, model-view-controller, xamarin.ios

In my test vb.net MVC web app, I have this json....

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Byte
    Public Sub New(name As String, age As Byte)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Age = age
    End Sub
End Class

Function GetPerson() As JsonResult
    Dim p As New Person("John Doe", 50)
    Return Json(p, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

And in Monotouch I've got this...

```
JsonObject j;
Uri address = new Uri("http://mysite/home/GetPerson");
HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (address);
using (HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse ()) {
    Stream s = httpRes.GetResponseStream ();
    j = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Load (s);
}
```

And this class...

```
Public Class Person {
    Public string Name { get; set; }
    Public byte Age { get; set; }
}
```

How do I parse the JsonObject j into class of Person? .. I hoped for something like Person p = (Person)j.value;

Thanks!
Mojo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would use int for Age. But assuming a JSON Structure like:

```
{   
    "Name" : "John Doe",
    "Age" : 100,
}
```

If you wanted to use the baked in System.Json stuff:

```
var person = new Person()
var obj = JsonObject.Parse(json);

person.Name = obj["Name"].ToString();
person.Age = (int)obj["Age"];
```

I would **HIGHLY** recommend using [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) though, it's a highly optimized extremely fast library for consuming JSON with compatibility with both MonoTouch and Mono for Android...out of the box!

You can check out the the API for consuming JSON with ServiceStack [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/UseCases/CentroidTests.cs).

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Yeah I looked at the ServiceStack today and tried to find some vb samples to learn from, but I couldn't. So I tried setting it up, but failed. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm using RestSharp on MonoTouch. Much like ServiceStack. RestSharp also works great.

Comment: [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) all the way! Does more than just de/serialization. It helps keeps your web client clean, removes lots of repeated cruft and deals with the many pitfalls of .NET's HttpWeb classes.

Answer (score 3):

Even if this question is now old, here is the solution I use.
With MonoTouch, you can use .net Json serialization mechanism based on DataContract.

```
[DataContract]
Public Class Person {
    [DataMember]
    Public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    Public byte Age { get; set; }
}
```

and use the DataContractJsonSerializer (found in System.Runtime.Serialization.Json)

```
Stream stream = httpRes.GetResponseStream ();
DataContractJsonSerializer jsSerializer = new  DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
Person person = (Person)jsSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

This way, the code is WCF compliant and work flawless on ms.net platform, mono and monotouch.